# cocos2D &lt not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have been asking a lot of questions lately, sorry. I get an error when **&lt** shows up.

```
-(void) SpritesDidCollide {

CCNode *player = [self getChildByTag:kTagPlayer];
CCNode *computer = [self getChildByTag:kTagComputer];

float xDif = computer.position.x - player.position.x;
float yDif = computer.position.y - player.position.y;
float distance = sqrt(xDif * xDif + yDif * yDif);

if (distance &lt 45;) {    //--------------------Right Here-------------------
    [self unschedule:@selector(SpritesDidCollide)];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1 scene:[GameOver node]]];
}

}
```

Comment: less than '<' ;
less or equal than '<='

Comment: I tried those, neither of them work, I get more errors...

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:]

Comment: We need more code to see.
Where do you call the method which crashes and how?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just:

```
if (distance < 45) {
```

Comment: Wait! Now the screen doesn't even load, my program crashes.

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:] Mean anything?

Answer (score 1):

Look at 'Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt'

your selector (SpritesDidCollide) isn't accepting ccTime...

change

```
-(void)SpritesDidCollide
```

to

```
-(void)SpritesDidCollide:(ccTime)dt
```

and change

```
[self unschedule:@selector(SpritesDidCollide:)]; // Note added colon : after method name
```

May also need to change the schedule call and add the colon : where ever you initially set it up

```
[self schedule: @selector(SpritesDidCollide:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (distance &lt 45;) {
```

Take a look again. To compare use comparison operators such as '==', '<', '>', '<=', '>='.
Inside of brackets in your case we do not need ';'. 
'(expression ;)' such construction is not acceptable.

```
if (distance < 45) {
```

Comment: The code theoretically works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try and go to that view, It crashes...If you wouldn't mind...Here's my entire file.

Comment: We cannot help you until we see your problem. Add some more code and error messages.

Comment: I added my entire file. Ill also add the Console error messages. One second.

Comment: *** Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:], /Users/GLaDOS/Documents/Xcode 4 Projects/2DPlatformer/2DPlatformer/libs/cocos2d/CCScheduler.m:110
2012-02-17 19:13:07.460 2DPlatformer[709:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt'

Comment: 1: Accept the response that answers your first question.  
2: Then, post a new question for your new issue.